# Meaning of "Where are you located?"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

What is the actual meaning of the sentence "*Where are you located?*". Is it referring to the place where the person living now (home) or his/her current location?(like asking where are you?).

Is it correct to use it for asking the current location (same as where are you?),  Like in a situation when I ask someone "Where are you?" few times but he/she did't understand or did't hear the question properly so using the sentence to asking the same question with emphasizing the Location part.

Comment: It depends on the context. Where did you find this sentence? Do you have example sentences?

Comment: Usually asking where are you now.

Comment: I'm voting to close as Primarily Opinion-based. Context is everything, and that should be obvious even if you're dealing with a foreign language. When a waitress asks you *What would you like?*, she doesn't expect you to reply *Eternal life and omniscience please. Oh - and the rest of the world would like a cure for cancer, if you have one.*

Comment: @FumbleF - I'd call that "Primarily Context-Based" – but I have no quarrel with a vote to put on hold until more details are furnished. (P.S. Good example with the waitress and the cancer cure.)

Comment: @J.R.♦: Obviously OP could provide sufficient context to make it completely unambiguous as to whether the questioner means *Where are you **right now**? Where do you **live**?* or *What is your designated **place of work**?*, for example. But then it would be too trivial to answer here anyway, so I don't see the point of thinking in terms of waiting until more details are furnished.

Comment: @Fumble - That part about waiting was just a reminder that we don't vote to close, we vote to put on hold (and to encourage the O.P. to at least think about rewording the question).

Comment: @J.R.♦: Actually, I now realize I was guilty of making unjustified assumptions there. It might well not be obvious to learners whether/how the additional word ***located*** affects the meaning (in a context where the near-synonymous ***based***, for example, would strongly imply *place of work* rather than *domicile* or *current location*). I stand by my closevote, but at least I can now see that in principle the question could be salvaged.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Question updated with some context details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Where are you located," is generally not used in AmE to ask where someone lives.  "Where do you live," would be more common and better understood.

"Where are you located," is commonly used to ask the location of a business or organization or, as you suggest, it can be used to ask and individual where they are currently located.

Comment: "Where are you at," or simply, "Where are you," are actually more common ways of asking for an individual's current location.